# Increase blob upload performance

Tags: c++, azure-storage

I am working on integrating a c++ application with Azure blob storage. 
To achieve this I have implemented a wrapper class around wastorage 4.0 APIs.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AzureStorage.h"
// Microsoft Azure Library Header Includes.
#include "was\storage_account.h"
#include "was\blob.h"

struct RadAzureData{
    azure::storage::cloud_storage_account storage_account;
    azure::storage::cloud_blob_client blob_client;
    azure::storage::cloud_blob_container container;
};

   RadAzureStorage::RadAzureStorage():
   RadCloudStorageInterface(RAD_STORAGE_TYPE::AZURE_CLOUD)
   {
   }

   RadAzureStorage::RadAzureStorage(std::string accountName1, std::string     accountKey1, std::string containerName1) :        RadCloudStorageInterface(RAD_STORAGE_TYPE::AZURE_CLOUD)
   {
       std::wstring accountNameWS(accountName1.begin(), accountName1.end());
       std::wstring accountKeyWS(accountKey1.begin(), accountKey1.end());
       std::wstring containerNameWS(containerName1.begin(), containerName1.end());
       d = new RadAzureData();
       accountName = accountNameWS;
       accountKey = accountKeyWS;
       containerName = containerNameWS;
       std::wstring connStr1 = L"AccountName=" + accountName + L";AccountKey=" + accountKey + L";DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https";
       d->storage_account =        azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::parse(connStr1.c_str());
       // Create a blob container
       d->blob_client = d->storage_account.create_cloud_blob_client();
       d->container = d->blob_client.get_container_reference(containerName.c_str());
       CreateContainer();
   }


   bool RadAzureStorage::CreateContainer()
   {
       try
       {
           d->container.create_if_not_exists();
       }

       catch (const azure::storage::storage_exception& e)
       {
          cout<<"Exception in container creation: " << e.what()<<endl;
          cout <<"The request that started at:" << e.result().start_time().to_string().c_str() << " and ended at " << e.result().end_time().to_string().c_str() << " resulted in HTTP status code " << e.result().http_status_code() << " and the request ID reported by the server was " << e.result().service_request_id().c_str()<<endl;
          return false;
       }
    return true;
   }

   bool RadAzureStorage::UploadFile(std::string blockBlobName, std::string dicomFileLocation)
   {
       std::wstring blockBlobNameWS(blockBlobName.begin(), blockBlobName.end());
       std::wstring dicomFileLocationWS(dicomFileLocation.begin(), dicomFileLocation.end());
       // Create a Block Blob Object.
       azure::storage::cloud_block_blob block_blob = d->container.get_block_blob_reference(blockBlobNameWS.c_str());
       // Upload Block Blob to container.
       try
       {
           block_blob.upload_from_file(dicomFileLocationWS.c_str());
       }
       catch (const azure::storage::storage_exception& e)
       {
           cout<< "Exception in file upload: " << e.what() << endl;
           cout<< "The request that started at:" << e.result().start_time().to_string().c_str() << " and ended at " << e.result().end_time().to_string().c_str() << " resulted in HTTP status code " << e.result().http_status_code() << " and the request ID reported by the server was " << e.result().service_request_id().c_str() << endl;
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
   #undef __FILENAME__
```

From the application, it instantiates RadAzureStorage class and calls UploadFile API.

```
   RadAzureStorage* clsi = new RadAzureStorage(accountname, acesskey,        containername);
   <<timer.start>>
   clsi->UploadFile(blockBlobName, file);
   <<timer.end>>
   cout << timer.ellapsedMilliSeconds<< "ms"<< endl;
```

UploadFile API takes 14-16 ms for file sizes ranging between 190-250 KB.

Are there some parameters on wastorage initialization that can be modified to achieve this under 10 ms.

The current testing environment is hosted in Azure South India:
1. VM: Windows server 2016, 4v Core, 16 GB ram.
2. Hot tier access, storage account.

Please note: similar logic is implemented on C# where upload per file is being achieved under 10 ms for the same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This delay could be also caused by the type of storage accounts used. When using Premium storage accounts, you get higher performance vs GPV1.

there's also a new product that's still in [Azure Premium blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-premium-block-blob-storage-is-now-generally-available/). Premium storage accounts are stored on SSD vs HDD, so you get a better performance as well when using GPV2 premium.

Comment: Adam, I have setup the storage account under StorageV2 (general purpose v2).

Comment: Adam, one more question? Are there any know bottlenecks in wastorage c++ module v4.0.0.